# jQuery help needed ---- Two controls one is setting the other is not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two controls one is setting the other is not.  Any jQuery Gurus that can assist would be great.  I am going to add all the code calls:

1. ```
   return {
   init: function (ctrl_IDs) {
       _benefitPlans.pop();
       _categories.pop();
       _definitions.pop();
       _diagGroups.pop();
       _ageGroups.pop();
       _placeOfServices.pop();
       _serviceID = getServiceID();

       if (ctrl_IDs) {
           _ids = ctrl_IDs;
       }

       initialHideEditPanels();
       initialButtonDisable();

       bindDatePickerEvents();
       bindButtonEvents();
       bindInputBlurEvents();
       bindCheckboxEvents();
       bindRadGridEvents();

       initialDataBind();

       toggleServiceCodeInputEnabled(false);
       toggleBenefitPlanInputEnabled(false);
      }
    }
   }(jQuery, $telerik));
   ```

We need to look at the bindDatePickerEvents();

```
 function bindDatePickerEvents() {
    bindDates($find(_ids.txtServiceCodeEffectiveDate), $find(_ids.txtServiceCodeEndDate));
    bindDates($find(_ids.txtBenefitPlanEffectiveDate), $find(_ids.txtBenefitPlanEndDate), _attrTypes.benefitPlan);//TODO RBD SW#6848
    bindDates($find(_ids.txtServiceCategoryEffectiveDate), $find(_ids.txtServiceCategoryEndDate), _attrTypes.serviceCategory);
    bindDates($find(_ids.txtServiceDefinitionEffectiveDate), $find(_ids.txtServiceDefinitionEndDate), _attrTypes.serviceDefinition);
    bindDates($find(_ids.txtDiagnosisGroupEffectiveDate), $find(_ids.txtDiagnosisGroupEndDate), _attrTypes.diagnosisGroup);
    bindDates($find(_ids.txtAgeGroupEffectiveDate), $find(_ids.txtAgeGroupEndDate), _attrTypes.ageGroup);
    bindDates($find(_ids.txtPlacesOfServiceEffectiveDate), $find(_ids.txtPlacesOfServiceEndDate), _attrTypes.placeOfService);
}
```

Next bindDates()

```
    function bindDates(effDate, endDate, attrType) {
    //Declare variables to be used in the JavaScript Function
    var effDateID = effDate.get_id();
    var endDateID = endDate.get_id();
    var tmp = attrType;

    $(effDate.get_element()).on('validDateEntered', { effID: effDateID, endID: endDateID, type: tmp }, function (evt) {
        setEffectiveDates($find(evt.data.effID), $find(evt.data.endID), evt.data.type);
    });

     effDate.add_dateSelected(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });

    effDate.get_dateInput().add_blur(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });

    endDate.add_dateSelected(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });

    endDate.get_dateInput().add_blur(function (sender, args) {
        validateDatesRange(effDate, endDate);
    });
}
```

Set Effective Dates

```
    function setEffectiveDates(effDateCtrl, endDateCtrl, attrType) {
    var type = attrType !== undefined ? attrType : -1,
        effDate = effDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(),
        endDate = endDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(), 
        effDateString = effDate == undefined ? '' : dateToString(effDate),
        endDateString = endDate == undefined ? '' : dateToString(endDate);

    switch (type) {
        //RBD CODING ON SATURDAY MORNING CARTOONS
        case _attrTypes.benefitPlan:
            _selected.benefitPlan.eff_date = effDateString;
            _selected.benefitPlan.end_date = endDateString; 
            break;
        case _attrTypes.serviceCategory:
            _selected.serviceCategory.eff_date = effDateString;
            _selected.serviceCategory.end_date = endDateString;
            break;
        case _attrTypes.serviceDefinition:
            _selected.serviceDefinition.eff_date = effDateString;
            _selected.serviceDefinition.end_date = endDateString;
            break;
        case _attrTypes.diagnosisGroup:
            _selected.diagnosisGroup.eff_date = effDateString;
            _selected.diagnosisGroup.end_date = endDateString;
            break;
        case _attrTypes.ageGroup:
            _selected.ageGroup.eff_date = effDateString;
            _selected.ageGroup.end_date = endDateString;
            break;
        case _attrTypes.placeOfService:
            _selected.placeOfService.eff_date = effDateString;
            _selected.placeOfService.end_date = endDateString;
            break;
        default:
            _details.eff_date = effDateString;
            _details.end_date = endDateString;
            break;
    }
}
```

Finalling validateDatesRange

```
function validateDatesRange(effDateCtrl, endDateCtrl) {
    var result = true,
        effDate = effDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(),
        endDate = endDateCtrl.get_selectedDate(),
        cell = $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).parents('td').first();

    if (effDate && endDate) {
        if (effDate > endDate) {
            var div = "<div class='errorMessage' style='display:none;'>Effective date must be less than end date.</div>";
            $(div).prependTo(cell).fadeIn();
            result = false;
        }
    }

    if (result) {
        cell.find('div.errorMessage').fadeOut(200, null, function () {     $(this).remove(); });
        $(effDateCtrl.get_element()).trigger('validDateEntered');            
    }
    return result;
}
```

Again, the problem here is the endDateCtrl is not changing the date.  When the page opens the data is populated in a Grid and the end user clicks on an edit button and this populates a panel.  However, the effDateCtrl shows the correct date, but the endDateCtrl does not, but if you click on the edit button twice the date populates.  I am stumped.

```
    function pageLoad() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            sc.init(getClientIDs());
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there a copy/paste weirdness in your first code block? I'd expect something before the `return {`, maybe a missing function declaration?

Comment: Klores I am going to post the whole script...

Comment: See jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/moojjoo/M3ukt/

Comment: Assuming that exactly matches your live code, there are a couple of your object variables that are missing ending `;`s - `_cached`, `_selected` and `_overlapDates`. I don't know if that's anything to do with your problem, but would be worth correcting.

Comment: How are you using `sc`?

Comment: sc is loaded onto a .NET .aspx page....

Comment: See above for code added.

Comment: Well, it all looks plausible. I'm not seeing anything that jumps out at me as being wrong. There are another couple of missing `;`s that I would add in, just in case they're upsetting the js (though I'd imagine that's unlikely). One for `var datestring` in `function dateToString(date)` and another for the `return { init: .... }` at the end.